# Spring Data JPA + Kotlin

Tags: spring, hibernate, kotlin, spring-data-jpa, hql

In Spring Data JPA trying to use interface projection technique :

```
interface DocInfoShort {
    var docTypeId: Int
}
```

And my DAO:

```
public interface DocRepository extends JpaRepository<Doc, Long> {
    @Query("select sum(cast(doc.isSent AS int)) as docTypeId" +
            "       from Doc doc group by docTypeId", nativeQuery = true)
    fun someQuery(): List<DocInfoShort>
}
```

but it is not working :

```
could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet"
```

How can i fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Just make `DocInfoShort` a class with a proper constructor and use the constructor syntax of JPQL in the query annotation:

```
@Query("select new full.package.name.DocInfoShort(sum(cast(doc.isSent AS int)))" +
       "from Doc doc group by docTypeId")
```